# Subset data with time window and equal / different column entries

Tags: r

```
A = c(100,101,102,103,104,105)
B = c(99,99,100,99.5,98,101)
C = c("D","S","D","D","S","D")
D = c(0110,0110,0110,0110,0110,0110)
data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

Hi all, 
I have this huge dataset, which I'm trying to subset. I put an example or a simplification  above, I hope it helps to understand my problem. 
So basically, I'm looking for all rows, where the entries in Column B and D are equal. For these rows, the difference (i.e. time difference) between the entries in Column A should be equal or within one second. In addition to that, the rows should have distinct entries in Column C. 
The code I'm looking for should therefore return data, where all these rows are listed. 
For my example, the output data should look like this.

```
[1] 100 99 D 110
[2] 101 99 S 110
```

structure(list(trd_exctn_dt = c(20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 
20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 
20130430L), trd_exctn_tm = c(62076, 62099, 62110, 62120, 62126, 
62173, 62215, 62231, 62266, 62280), trd_rpt_dt = c(20130430L, 
20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 
20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L), trd_rpt_tm = c(62077, 62150, 
62111, 62121, 62127, 62174, 62218, 62232, 62326, 62283), msg_seq_nb = c(77464L, 
77513L, 77483L, 77493L, 77499L, 77526L, 77550L, 77556L, 77609L, 
77577L), entrd_vol_qt = c(1e+06, 2e+06, 250000, 1e+06, 1e+06, 
1e+06, 1e+06, 2e+06, 2e+06, 1e+06), rptd_pr = c(100.337, 99.922, 
100.337, 99.922, 100.391, 100.059, 100.391, 100.426, 100.434, 
100.391), rpt_side_cd = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("trd_exctn_dt", 
"trd_exctn_tm", "trd_rpt_dt", "trd_rpt_tm", "msg_seq_nb", "entrd_vol_qt", 
"rptd_pr", "rpt_side_cd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(12791L, 
474L, 33360L, 467L, 12795L, 45846L, 12804L, 12806L, 33373L, 12810L
))

Comment: In your example you have no rows where columns B and D are equal

Comment: I meant to select rows, where entries in B are equal and in D as well, i.e. observation 1 and 2, as they both have "99" in B and "0110" in D. 
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've tried a solution below. However you haven't mentioned how you want the data (rows) in case there are multiple B,D combinations and how to deal with distinct C values in case you have duplicates. Below I return all rows in one dataset and I return distinct C values based on column A (time ordered).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the data you provided above and it seems to work for me.

```
library(dplyr)

dt = structure(list(trd_exctn_dt = c(20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L), 
                    trd_exctn_tm = c(62076, 62099, 62110, 62120, 62126, 62173, 62215, 62231, 62266, 62280), 
                    trd_rpt_dt = c(20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L, 20130430L),
                    trd_rpt_tm = c(62077, 62150, 62111, 62121, 62127, 62174, 62218, 62232, 62326, 62283), 
                    msg_seq_nb = c(77464L, 77513L, 77483L, 77493L, 77499L, 77526L, 77550L, 77556L, 77609L, 77577L), 
                    entrd_vol_qt = c(1e+06, 2e+06, 250000, 1e+06, 1e+06, 1e+06, 1e+06, 2e+06, 2e+06, 1e+06),
                    rptd_pr = c(100.337, 99.922, 100.337, 99.922, 100.391, 100.059, 100.391, 100.426, 100.434, 100.391), 
                    rpt_side_cd = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                            .Label = c("B", "S"), class = "factor")), 
               .Names = c("trd_exctn_dt", "trd_exctn_tm", "trd_rpt_dt", "trd_rpt_tm", "msg_seq_nb", "entrd_vol_qt", "rptd_pr", "rpt_side_cd"), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(12791L, 474L, 33360L, 467L, 12795L, 45846L, 12804L, 12806L, 33373L, 12810L ))

dt

#       trd_exctn_dt trd_exctn_tm trd_rpt_dt trd_rpt_tm msg_seq_nb entrd_vol_qt rptd_pr rpt_side_cd
# 12791     20130430        62076   20130430      62077      77464      1000000 100.337           B
# 474       20130430        62099   20130430      62150      77513      2000000  99.922           B
# 33360     20130430        62110   20130430      62111      77483       250000 100.337           B
# 467       20130430        62120   20130430      62121      77493      1000000  99.922           B
# 12795     20130430        62126   20130430      62127      77499      1000000 100.391           B
# 45846     20130430        62173   20130430      62174      77526      1000000 100.059           B
# 12804     20130430        62215   20130430      62218      77550      1000000 100.391           S
# 12806     20130430        62231   20130430      62232      77556      2000000 100.426           S
# 33373     20130430        62266   20130430      62326      77609      2000000 100.434           S
# 12810     20130430        62280   20130430      62283      77577      1000000 100.391           S



dt %>% 
  arrange(trd_exctn_tm) %>%                              # order time column
  group_by(rptd_pr, trd_exctn_dt) %>%                    # group by appropriate columns
  mutate(Count1 = n(),                                   # count how many rows there are for each combination
         Count2 = n_distinct(rpt_side_cd)) %>%           # count how many unique values of last column there are for each combination
  filter(Count1 > 1 & Count2 > 1) %>%                    # keep only combinations with multiple rows and multiple unique values in last column
  mutate(Dist = trd_exctn_tm - min(trd_exctn_tm)) %>%    # calculate distance based on time column
  filter(Dist <= 160) %>%                                # keep only rows with appropriate distance 
  distinct(rpt_side_cd, .keep_all=T) %>%                 # select distinct values (order based on time column)
  ungroup() %>%                                          # forget the grouping
  select(-Count1, -Count2, -Dist)

# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#    trd_exctn_dt trd_exctn_tm trd_rpt_dt trd_rpt_tm msg_seq_nb entrd_vol_qt rptd_pr rpt_side_cd
#           <int>        <dbl>      <int>      <dbl>      <int>        <dbl>   <dbl>      <fctr>
# 1     20130430        62126   20130430      62127      77499        1e+06 100.391           B
# 2     20130430        62215   20130430      62218      77550        1e+06 100.391           S
```

If this is the output you want you have to check you're using the latest version of R (3.3.1) and `dplyr` (0.5.0) as this is what I'm using.

If you want the tibble output saved as a new data frame then simply do

```
dt2 = dt %>% ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. 
 I tried to run it but it would return an error code : Error in UseMethod("arrange_") : 
  no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "function"

I installed the dplyr package before; I have to add that I am not really familiar with it though.

Comment: You might need to use the latest versions of the packages. Also, not sure if you are using any other packages and they interact with each other. Try to clean your workspace, install the latest version of `dplyr` and run the example again.

Comment: It worked with your sample dataframe but when I tried to replicate it for my data, I got two errors. 
The first one appears right after the 2nd mutate order: Error: invalid subscript type 'double'.
The second one appears at the end and goes back to the first one, I think: Error in filter_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  object 'Dist' not found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something is wrong with the type of values in A column. Try to transform this column/variable to a numeric variable, using `as.numeric`.

Comment: The values in the column are already numeric. 
They were time designations before I converted them into numeric values with the lubridate package.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same commands? `Dist` is not created for some reason and most likely due to the `min(A)`. How did you convert the time designations? Which command did you use? if you do `class(data$A)` do you get "numeric"?

Comment: Another option is to select a sample of rows of your dataset (let's say top 20) and use the `dput()` command to be able to reproduce the exact column types you are working with. You have to post under your question the output of the `dput()` command. You can do that on the dataset you have after all your transformations and before running my script.

Comment: The class of data$A in that case got me numeric indeed.
just pasted the output below my question.

Comment: The pair of rows should have equal entries in rptd_pr and trd_exctn_dt.  The rpt_side_cd should be different though and trd_exctn_tm should not be apart more than 50 seconds.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll be able to spot the problem if I work with that dataset. I'll work on that tomorrow though.

Comment: Thanks! I've put a smaller dataset above. Relax the time window in that case to 160 seconds, so that we actually would have a match in that set.

Comment: Is it possible to include a command into the code that would return a new dataframe with the rows from the tibble matrix? Tried to run it with as.data.frame(), which would not give me the desired results.

Comment: The code works fine but the code should get rid off the first 2; I just need rows like #3 and #4 where rptd_pr is equal.

Comment: Cool. They are there because they had multiple rows but not unique values in last column. Will update my code soon.